# Рваные массивы. Сдвиг элементов на K позиций

Tags: c#

Влево получилось сделать а вот вправо не могу сделать, подскажите.

```
private static void ShiftArrayLeft(int[][] array, int shift)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                int realShift = shift % array[i].Length;
                while (realShift-- > 0)
                {
                    int temp = array[i][0];
                    for (int j = array[i].Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        int val = array[i][j];
                        array[i][j] = temp;
                        temp = val;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Помогите осуществить циклический сдвиг на k элементов вправо.

```
private static void ShiftArrayRight(int[][] array, int shift)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                int temp = array[i][array[i].Length - 1];
                for (int j = 0; j < array[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    int val = array[i][j];
                    array[i][j] = temp;
                    temp = val;
                }
```

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function shiftRight() {
  var temp = array[array.length - 1];
  for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
    var val = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
    temp = val;
  }
}

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
  shiftRight();
}
```

Comment: Или ваш метод не правильно работает, или мой неправильно со сдигом влево работает, немогу понять

Comment: Такой код работает великолепно с одномерным массивом, но ни как не с рваным..

Comment: @АртемМазуров При чем здесь "рваный массив"? Вы сдвигаете каждый одномерный массив индивидуально. Замените Ваш код внутри `while` на мой - и все. Или Вы туда подаете отрицательное число?

Comment: Спасибо, то я чуть не так делал.

Comment: @АртемМазуров Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.